# Read symbols like string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Python 3 and write input to variable like a string, but I've got something different. For example: from `s = input()` where input is `1-2` I've got `-1`? Why I've got a different result and how can I fix it to get `1-2`?

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Apr  7 2015, 08:05:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str(1-2)
'-1'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Python 2...?

Comment: I cheked it and updated my post, looks like python 3

Comment: I don't see `input` anywhere in there...

Comment: If you want `1-2` then you need to make sure that `input()`, (whatever that is) is seen as a string. Now python sees it as number where it can do math with. And then 1 - 2 = -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking python to evaluate the mathematical expression:

```
1-2
```

and then convert that to a string - so obviously you get:

```
'-1'
```

This should work fine in python 3:

```
user_input = input('enter text:')
```

If you want the example you provided to work, just define a string literal and don't worry about the `str()` function

```
test = '1-2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking python to turn the answer to 1-2 into a string, and 1-2 is -1. This is simple to solve, all that is needed are quotation marks (or speech marks) as these symbolise a string.

```
print('1-2')
string = input('Enter string: ')
```

When using input, it acts like a string anyway unless you use int(input())

```
integer = int(input('Enter an integer: )
```